# Best way to check if a set ok keys exist

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

What's the best way to check withs keys exist from a set of Keys using Objectify?

Currently I'm using:

```
List<T> list2LookFor= ...; 
Map<Key<T>,T> objects = ofy().load().keys(list2LookFor);
```

But I really don't need to load all the instances, is there a way to only check the keys that exist?
I see that there is a `Keys()`method but then I cant batch it.

PD: In my use case I can expect about 50-100 keys in `list2LookFor` and loaded entity has about 5 or 6 fields.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the cheapest way to test for entity existence in GAE is to perform get-by-key.